# Garbage-characters from R knitR (Rnw) snippets

Tags: r, knitr

Some results are producing garbage. For example, t-test is giving some ugly characters "^^I" like in this snippet:
[image]

It can be removed manually thou, in tex-file which then must be recompiled (but only tex, not Rnw). Any idea how can this be eliminated? Thanks!

Comment: Cannot reproduce this.

Comment: Maybe an encoding issue? What is your `Sys.getlocale`? Is it just when you knit, or if you run that line in the console do you get weird characters? What does your document header/YAML frontmatter look like?

Comment: Thought about encoding as well. These characters are right there where `print.t.test` puts the tab command `\t`

Comment: `Sys.getlocale()`
> [1] "en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8"